# What does "\e" mean?

Tags: escaping, dot-emacs

I came across the following line in a .emacs config file:

```
(define-key scheme-mode-map "\e\t" 'scheme-smart-complete)
```

It's binding key sequence `\e\t` to the function `scheme-smart-complete`, but I don't know what `\e` is, and it turns out it's impossible to Google (even putting quotes around `\e` didn't help with the search).

What's `\e`?

Comment: I know this question is for emacs, but if you're here looking for what `\e` means in `zsh`, it can either be the escape *or* alt key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the escape key.

See the [emacs basic character syntax guide](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Char-Syntax.html).

So \e\t is escape-tab.

ian.